# what is it used for _.once in underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I just look at the once API of source in underscore.js, then wandering what is it the used for 
in the method, it seems doing nothing:

```
func = null
```

the source:

```
  _.once = function(func) {
    var ran = false, memo;
    return function() {
      if (ran) return memo;
      ran = true;
      memo = func.apply(this, arguments);
      func = null;
      return memo;
    };
  };
```

Comment: You want to know about the method, or why `func = null` is done?

Comment: [Have you checked the documentation??](http://underscorejs.org/#once)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What the function does can be found in the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#once):

> Creates a version of the function that can only be called one time. Repeated calls to the modified function will have no effect, returning the value from the original call. Useful for initialization functions, instead of having to set a boolean flag and then check it later.

Why set `func = null` is explained in this [commit message](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/ac7f640a76a38318b495a0e30995c02ed1eae43d):

> Assuming we'll never run the wrapped function again on _.once(), we can
>   assign null to the `func` variable, so function (and all its inherited
>   scopes) may be collected by GC if needed.

Answer (score 3):

From the official underscorejs website:

**once** _.once(function)

Creates a version of the function that can only be called one time. Repeated calls to the modified function will have no effect, returning the value from the original call. Useful for initialization functions, instead of having to set a boolean flag and then check it later.

```
var initialize = _.once(createApplication);
initialize();
initialize();
// Application is only created once.
```

http://underscorejs.org/#once

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you are asking about the entire function or just the `func = null` line. If the latter, see just step 3, below.

---

`ran` is initially false.

When you run the returned function for the first time:

1. `ran` is set to `true`
2. the function passed into `once` is called
3. the function reference is deleted (presumably to aid garbage collection)
4. `memo` is returned

When you run the returned function again (since `ran` is now `true`):

1. `memo` is returned

Comment: yes, it seems I didn't explain clear, I want to know what the `func = null` is for.

Comment: Removing the reference to it allows it to be garbage collected so it doesn't eat memory.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth pointing out is that the `memo` will hold the result of the initially executed function.

So when you call your function again, it will not be executed but the result of the first call will be returned.