# Stop a jquery function execution twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a js function executed once in my code.Either in `resize` or `load` handler 
.I have a function which is executed if one statement is true and another in the window resize.So when my statement is true then the function is executed and i do not want the function executed again if the window is resized.

### My js codes are

```
if(vertical){
     vertical();
}
```

And

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   vertical();
}
```

And

```
var vertical = function(){
  ..........
}
```

i also prevent execution if window is resized multiple times

Comment: Try underscore's [.once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166101/what-is-it-used-for-once-in-underscore) function.

Comment: How about using a flag variable (boolean)? Set it to false first, then inside the function check it it's not true then execute your code and set it to true

Comment: jQuery also has [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: I think what you want to use is debounce...

Answer (score 2):

You have to use some kind of flags for that:

```
var flag = false;

function vertical() {
   if (!flag) {
       flag = true;
       // do your job
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this via a semaphore.

So you set a flag to false and before you call the function you only want to call once check `if(flag)` , execute the code and set flag to true

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to check if the function is fired

```
var execute = true;
if(vertical){
    if (execute) {    
        vertical();
        execute = false;
    }

}
$(window).resize(function(){
   if (execute) {    
        vertical();
        execute = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function at the end of vertical() function so when it will execute at first it will unbind the event for next window resize.

Comment: What about manual call of this function? `onClick="return vertical();"`

Comment: But think about there is `vertical = true` and there is one execution and another is on `resize` . so there is two